# microsoft graph cant get refresh token

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am using msal for getting tokens as per below:

```
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: config.MS_CLIENT_ID,
        authority: config.AAD_ENDPOINT + 'consumers', //config.TENANT_ID,
        clientSecret: config.MS_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }
};


const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(msalConfig);

const authCodeUrlParameters = {
                        scopes: ["Mail.ReadWrite"],
                        redirectUri: config.MS_REDIRECT_URI,
                    };

   // get url to sign user in and consent to scopes needed for application
  cca.getAuthCodeUrl(authCodeUrlParameters);

  let tokenReq = {
                        code: ctx.params.Token,
                        scopes: ["Mail.ReadWrite"],
                        redirectUri: config.MS_REDIRECT_URI
                    }
                    const tokenRes = await cca.acquireTokenByCode(tokenReq);
```

I am not getting refresh token from acquireTokenByCode method

Answer (score 0):

First to implement refresh token, you need the scope [offline_access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#offline_access) incorporated in your flow.

That said, Msal-Node des not expose the refresh token. It will use the refresh token internally to renew the access token. Check [this thread](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2836) for more details. You use **acquireTokenSilent** when you need an access token as Msal will take care of managing the refresh token.